# Error when compiling fortran code in python 3.5.5 (jupyter) on W10-64bit

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

Cannot compile fortran code on W10 64 with f2py although tried few ways

Environment:

- Windows 10, 64bit
- mingw-64bit installed
- Python 3.5.5 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

Added the mingw\bin to the path, 
also 
`C_INCLUDE_PATH = c:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\include`

In jupyter notebook I have added 2 codeblocks:

```
    %%writefile add.f90
C
      SUBROUTINE ZADD(A,B,C,N)
C
      DOUBLE COMPLEX A(*)
      DOUBLE COMPLEX B(*)
      DOUBLE COMPLEX C(*)
      INTEGER N
      DO 20 J = 1, N
         C(J) = A(J)+B(J)
 20   CONTINUE
      END
```

`!python "c:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\Scripts\f2py.py" -m add add.f90 -c`

Error:

> running build
> running config_cc
> unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
> running config_fc
> unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
> running build_src
> build_src
> building extension "add" sources
> f2py options: []
> f2py:> C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5uof322x\src.win-amd64-3.5\addmodule.c
> creating C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5uof322x\src.win-amd64-3.5
> Reading fortran codes...
>     Reading file 'add.f90' (format:fix)
> Post-processing...
>    Block: add
>           Block: zadd
> Post-processing (stage 2)...
> Building modules...
>   Building module "add"...
>         Constructing wrapper function "zadd"...
> getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
> getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
> getarrdims:warning: assumed shape array, using 0 instead of '*'
>           zadd(a,b,c,n)
>  Wrote C/API module "add" to file "C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5uof322x\src.win-amd64-3.5\addmodule.c"
>   adding 'C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5uof322x\src.win-amd64-3.5\fortranobject.c' to sources.
>   adding 'C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5uof322x\src.win-amd64-3.5' to include_dirs.
> copying C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5uof322x\src.win-amd64-3.5
> copying C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp5uof322x\src.win-amd64-3.5
> build_src: building npy-pkg config files
> running build_ext
> Looking for python35.dll
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\Scripts\f2py.py", line 28, in 
>     main()
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 648, in main
>     run_compile()
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\f2py2e.py", line 633, in run_compile
>     setup(ext_modules=[ext])
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 166, in setup
>     return old_setup(**new_attr)
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
>     dist.run_commands()
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
>     self.run_command(cmd)
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>     cmd_obj.run()
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
>     old_build.run(self)
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
>     self.run_command(cmd_name)
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
>     self.distribution.run_command(command)
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
>     cmd_obj.run()
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 117, in run
>     force=self.force)
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 596, in new_compiler
>     compiler = klass(None, dry_run, force)
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 96, in **init**
>     msvcr_success = build_msvcr_library()
>   File "C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py", line 329, in build_msvcr_library
>     if int(msvcr_name.lstrip('msvcr')) < 80:
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

If I added `--fcompiler=gfortran` I got `Unknown vendor: "gfortran"` error.

Tried this way as well:

```
import numpy.f2py as f2py
source="""
subroutine foo
  print*, "Hello world!"
end subroutine
"""
f2py.compile(source, extension = 'f90', modulename='hello', extra_args = '--fcompiler=g95')
```

I added some extra print command into f2py__init__.py and also change this:

```
#status, output = exec_command(c)
status = os.system(c)
```

otherwise it removed all backslash from the executeable (issue with distutils).

> C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphcpqwx21f90 
> subroutine foo
>   print*, "Hello world!"
> end subroutine
> C:\Users\Laszlo\Anaconda3\python.exe -c "import numpy.f2py as f2py2e;f2py2e.main()"  -c -m hello C:\Users\Laszlo\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphcpqwx21f90 --fcompiler=g95
> 1

```
import hello
hello.foo()
```

> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in ()
> ----> 1 import hello
>       2 hello.foo()
> ImportError: No module named 'hello'

Now I have no idea how to get it work on my W10/Anaconda.
Please help me to solve this!
Thank you in advance!
L.

Comment: Tried earlier. Unfortunately had the same result.

Comment: In `numpy\distutils\mingw32ccompiler.py the from numpy.distutils.misc_util import (msvc_runtime_library, get_build_architecture)` seems to be the problem, because `msvcr_name = msvc_runtime_library()` does not initialize it.

Comment: msvc_runttime_library() results None because my sys.version is "3.5.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Apr  7 2018, 04:52:34) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]" where 1900 is not listed in the function.

Comment: upgraded numpy. Now the f2py.compile runs forever w/o error.

Comment: Installed fortranmagic which works. But when I run it with -vvv to have advanced log in jupyter notebook I saw tons of warnings, so it seems obsolote. So there must be something with numpy and distutils. I just started Fortran, so a bit challenging.